# Spotify Play Button control via browser extension

Tags: spotify, browser-extension

can I control (play & pause) a Spotify Play button with a browser extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play button is inside an iframe. If browser extensions can get at content inside iframes, then I guess so.

This question is quite generic - why don't you give it a try and find out?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, technically is possible but I don't know if it's legally possible too. In Spotify Term of Service there is not something like this